# ulong / unsinged long not working any more, has C changed standards?

Tags: c, mingw

Came back to `C` almost after 20 years... figuring out my code from 2003 no longer compiles? (Under linux then, now in MinGW64). I am using the `ulong` type, it gives an error:

> rec.c:102:1: error: unknown type name 'ulong'; did you mean 'long'?

So, I tried to fix it by adding typedef:

```
typedef unsinged long ulong;
```

to which the compiler says:

```
rec.c:33:17: error: expected ';' before 'long'
 typedef unsinged long ulong;
                 ^~~~~
```

I am totally confused. This is supposed to be a normal typedef in C! Has C changed its standards in the last 18 years?

Comment: Typo. `unsinged` -> `unsigned`. Voting to close. Be more careful. Check spelling before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Nothing called `ulong` has ever existed in any C standard.
2. "Unsinged" is a typo, it's `unsigned`.

Comment: It should be closed and commented, not answered

Comment: thanks for the 2! But I don't agree with 1. Internet is full of `ulong` type.

Comment: @0___________ The `ulong` part is a valid question. If it was a typo alone then indeed it should be closed.

Comment: @Tomas Follow the C standard, not "the Internet".

Comment: @Lundin I bet that OP was using C# before, thus ulong